# Workflow migration to flows

Tags: workflow, workflowrule

I have tried migration of workflows and I have used the feature multiple currencies and even then migration to flows is possible.

Attaching the worflow rule and workflow action.
[image]

[image]

So my question is I have read that migration shouldn't be possible while referencing multiple currency anywhere in the workflow. Why is it possible here?

Comment: I would have thought your field update would set currencyIsoCode to `USD`, not `USA`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&type=5&id=sf.migrate_to_flow_tool_considerations_workflow.htm) points

> Workflow rules that contain the following can’t migrate with the Migrate to Flow tool. Multiple currencies

I was able to reproduce the scenario you provided.

The limitation applies when you have some currency data type field (Amount) in the entry criteria and have multi currency enabled in the org . In such a case the migration to flow will not work for particular workflow using **Migrate to flow** .

[image]

[image]

I hope you have used the currencyIsoCode not the currency field so the workflow gets migrated.